# HTML canvas fill difference on Firefox vs Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, canvas, fill

Consider the snippet below - available on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Xqu5U/2/

```
ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    ctx.arc(i * 10, 50 + Math.sin(i * 0.5) * 15, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
}

ctx.fill();
```

[image: difference between canvas fill on chrome and firefox]

It works as expected on Google Chrome, but Firefox renders a fill from the last arc to the first one.
How can the snippet above be updated to get Firefox drawing the arcs exactly like Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to get it working: http://jsfiddle.net/Xqu5U/3/.
Basically just add `ctx.closePath()` inside the `for` loop. Not sure if this is the best solution though...

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old question but for the future reference:

```
ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.beginPath()
ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000'

for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    ctx.arc(i * 10, 50 + Math.sin(i * 0.5) * 15, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2)
    ctx.closePath()
}

ctx.fill()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's really old, but someone just pointed me to here.

The problem was a chrome bug (now fixed since an undetermined long time). FF behavior was correct.

`arc()` method doesn't include a `moveTo(x, y)` call, but a `lineTo` one.

So in order to get your desired result, you just have to call `ctx.moveTo(nextCX + radius, nextCY)` where `nextCX` and `nextCY` are the center x and y coordinates of your next arc to be drawn. We add `radius` to the x position because, when the arc's starting angle is set to `0`, the arc is being drawn from 3 o'clock, without this `+ radius`, we would still have an internal `lineTo(cx + radius, cy)` being added, visible when calling `stroke()`.

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.fillStyle = '#FF0000';
for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    // you need to moveTo manually.
    ctx.moveTo(i * 10 + 2, 50 + Math.sin(i * 0.5) * 15)
    ctx.arc(i * 10, 50 + Math.sin(i * 0.5) * 15, 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
}
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't have really something to do about it...

It's the way both browser's work...

You can always design it with CSS with the right commands to make it the same...

Go to http://w3schools.com and find what you need for doing that :)

Good luck !

Comment: My question is regarding canvas only. Surely the red dots in the example could be done with CSS, but the example is just an isolated version of a problem that I found in a bigger application with canvas.