# No Auto Object Connect Javascript Canvas

Tags: javascript, object, canvas

If I draw an object made of ctx.lineTo(), the object doesn't finish off and connect. As you can see, I drew a triangle, and the tip looks flat. Two of them are pointy, though. Anyone know why? Thanks in advance!

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(10,13.031);
ctx.lineTo(13.5,6.969);
ctx.lineTo(6.5,6.969);
ctx.lineTo(10,13.031);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue most probably occurring because, your `x` and `y` coordinates are not appropriate as you are using floating point values.

Though you could use **[`lineCap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineCap)** and **[`lineJoin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/lineJoin)** method to make it smoother

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

ctx.scale(11, 11); // for better visibility

ctx.lineWidth = 1;
ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineCap = "round";
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.moveTo(10, 13.031);
ctx.lineTo(13.5, 6.969);
ctx.lineTo(6.5, 6.969);
ctx.lineTo(10, 13.031);
//ctx.closePath() //<-- this also could be used
ctx.stroke();
```

```css
body{margin:0;overflow:hidden}canvas{border:1px solid #d3d3d3}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="218" height="218"></canvas>
```

*or, you could also use `ctx.closePath()` before `ctx.stroke()`*

Comment: Your answer is incorrect, it only looks correct because you set lineJoin and lineCap as round. If you use any other setting you will see that the line has not joined. The only way to join the start and end of a path is with closePath

Answer (score 0):

In your case instead of 3rd `lineTo` you need to just `ctx.closePath()`
And then you can fill your shape with color =)

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

ctx.lineWidth = 1;

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(10,13);
ctx.lineTo(13.5,6.969);
ctx.lineTo(6.5,6.969);
ctx.closePath();

ctx.strokeStyle = "orange";
ctx.stroke();

ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
ctx.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: @Kaiido according to ES standards it *supposed* to, but it doesn't work properly on Firefox =) That's why it's recommended to always closePath before filling ;) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060495/html-canvas-fill-difference-on-firefox-vs-chrome

Comment: This was a chrome bug, now fixed. FF behavior was the correct one, OP of this question should have added ctx.moveTo in between its `arc` calls : http://jsfiddle.net/Xqu5U/13/

Comment: My bad (about standards), but in my Firefox 53 it still work differently with `closePath` and without. https://jsfiddle.net/qyetsvk8/

Comment: Yes you are calling both stroke and fill, missed it in my first comment (now deleted for this reason) https://jsfiddle.net/qyetsvk8/1/